# Outlook 2013 receive invitation in weird format

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I personally have never used Outlook before, however a colleague of mine is running into sort of a weird problem and asking me to help.  He is using Outlook 2013.

Whenever he receives any email that includes an invitation or has anything to do with the calendar, that whole email turns into an unrecognizable format with base64 encoded as well as some raw html [example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxvPs.png). The calendar is shown in a weird format as well [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Jvp.png).

I asked microsoft on this issue and they said the product is too old to receive any support.  I've been researching about this issue over the weekend but yield no result so hopefully I can receive some help in this community and perhaps learn a bit more about the issue.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem with his personal email account ? or his works email account ? if it's the latter he should take this up with you IT department.

Comment: Yes it is his work email, however his other colleagues don't have that problem at all and only his email, or computer or the way outlook was installed/setup.  Unfortunately it is a small company so there is no dedicated IT dept.

Comment: Does this issue happen if your colleague exit Outlook client and receive calendar related emails within OWA? Have you tried it with Outlook safe mode (outlook.exe /safe)?

Comment: He's using his company domain email so the OWA says Microsoft account doesn't exist.  Tried with safe mode but still getting the issue

Comment: So you are not using an Exchange account? Who is your email provider? Does your  email account have a webmail interface?

Comment: No it's not an Exchange account, it is the company's private email and yes it does have a web interface

Comment: So how the emails/meetings are showing in the web interface? Were these emails sent from external users or internal users?